# labeling figures as table

Tags: tables, floats, labels

P.S. I have figured it out. I simply added

```
\begin{table}
\end{table}
```

instead of figure environment

I am new to latex, trying to figure out how to write a simple paper.

I have a figure (a jpeg file) but it is actually a table. Latex labels it as "figure 1", I want to make it "Table 1" Is it possible?

I tried to have the figure in a table environment but it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{pic1}[h]
\caption{this is actually table1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could use `table` instead of `figure` (the actual content is 'completely' irrelevant, but `\includegraphics{pic}[h]` looks strange!). In addition, your example does not compile, since there is no `\usepackage{graphicx}` at all.

Comment: thanks, It worked! I did not want to paste a huge code :) I guess that is why it is not working.

Comment: The best way to say thanks over here is to accept answers that lead you to a solution. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Answer (score 4):

It's always possible to use an `\includegraphics` command within a `table` environment, but the other question is, whether the included 'table' looks like like a table.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\includegraphics{pic1}
\caption{this is actually table1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Alternative solution:**

Do not use the `table` environment (or `figure` environment at all) and use `\captionof{table}` from `caption` package. This figure/table will not float, however.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\begin{table}
\centering
\includegraphics{pic1}
\caption{this is actually a table}
\end{table}

Alternatively (non-floating)

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{pic1}
\captionof{table}{This is actually a table too}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I used `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` for this image actually